# [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, pscollectionview

I get this error here

```
+(CGFloat)heightForViewWithObject:(id)object inColumnWidth:(CGFloat)columnWidth {

NSString *titleText = [object objectForKey:@"title"];
}
```

object should be an `NSDictionary` instead its a `NSCFString`, it was working i don’t know what I did and now its not running. I am using a modified `PSCollectionView`.

Comment: You are assuming that `obj` is an `NSDictionary` but you are passing it an `NSString` object instead.  Ah you already said that.  Why post the question?

Comment: Are you using a web service that returns JSON? If you are, then it's possible that your server encountered an error and instead of returning your a nested JSON that's in NSDictionary form, it returned you an error message string.

Comment: Yes im using a web service that returns JSON. Let me check what is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `object` sometimes is NSDictionary and sometimes is NSString you can check it and process it differently:

```
+(CGFloat)heightForViewWithObject:(id)object inColumnWidth:(CGFloat)columnWidth {

    NSString *titleText = [object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class] ] ? [object objectForKey:@"title"] : object;
}
```

> (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass
>
> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of given
>   class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class.

Comment: well thanks that will be useful for the future but now i have to find what did i do that my web service returns a string now instead of JSOn